# Create product in code: Transaction errors (please HELP, critical!) - NEW!

Tags: product, transaction

I am fetching products from **external API** and create magento products out of this data. I use Magento 1.9.
After a **few** `inserts/updates`, I get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back
```

I use following code to create products in for each:

```
try
{
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku("xxxx");
    if(!$productId)
    {
        // new product
        $product->setStoreId(1);
        $product->setWebsiteIds([1]);
        $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime("now"));
        $product->setUpdatedAt(strtotime("now"));
        $product->setTypeId("simple");
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $product->setSku("xxxx");
        $product->setCategoryIds([12]);
        $product->setEan($ean);
        $product->setWeight($weight * 1000);
    }
    else 
    {
        // load existing product
        $product = $product->load($productId);

        // reset images
        $mediaApiItems = $mediaApi->items($productId);
        foreach($mediaApiItems as $item)
        {
            $mediaApi->remove($productId, $item["file"]);
        }
        $product->save();

        // load again with new image data
        $product = $product->load($productId);
    }


    $product->setName("title");
    $product->setDescription("desc");
    $product->setShortDescription("desc");
    $product->setIsMassupdate(true);
    $product->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);
    $product->setName("xxxx");
    $product->setCountryOfManufacture("USA");
    $product->setPrice(0.00);
    $product->setMetaTitle($articleStruct["title"]);
    $product->setMetaDescription("desc");

    // attributes
    $product->setAttributeSetId(10);
    $attr = [
                    "manufacterer" => "brand",
                    "modell" => "modell",
                    "custom_stock_status" => "",
                    "hide_default_stock_status" => 1,
                    "custom_stock_status_qty_based" => 0,
                    "farbe_konf" => 15,
                    "delivery_time" => $this->delivery
            ];
    $product->addData($attr);
    $product->setTaxClassId(1);

    $product->setStockData([
                    "use_config_manage_stock" => 0,
                    "manage_stock" => 1,
                    "min_sale_qty" => 1,
                    "max_sale_qty" => 1,
                    "is_in_stock" => 1,
                    "qty" => 1
            ]);
    $product->setStatus(1);

    $product->setMediaGallery(["images"=>[], "values"=>[]]);
    foreach ($articleStruct["images"] as $i => $imageUrl)
    {
        $saveLocation = $imageSaveDir . basename($imageUrl);

        // save image in file system
        if (!file_exists($saveLocation))
        {
            $curl = $this->getCurlClient($imageUrl);
            $data = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            file_put_contents($saveLocation, $data);
        }

        if ($i == 0)
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($saveLocation, ["image", "thumbnail", "small_image"], false, false);
        else
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($saveLocation, [], false, false);
    }

    $product->save();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    throw $e;
}
```

what is wrong?